What does this statement actually mean?
Here is a quote from the book The Complete Yes Minister"1 on the internal workings of government:

Bernard reminded us. ‘That private projects are more socially responsible with government money, and government projects are more efficient with private investment.’ (Source)

I am unable to fathom what this means. Could someone kindly guide me to its true meaning. I am not sure if Politics stackexchange is the correct place to ask this.

1 Available from numerous sources

What is unclear?  Do you know what a "Private project" or a "government project" is?  Do you know what "socially responsible" means? Do you know what "efficient" means? There is no deep "true" meaning here.  Just the obvious meaning that comes from the words.  Please clarify your question.

"Yes Minister" is a situation comedy.  Most of the "meaning" here is that it is funny due to irony.

I would argue that all the Medicare and Medicaid fraud in the US shows that statement isn’t true.

A breakdown, "Private Projects" does that mean super marks and malls? "Socially responsible", what does that mean is it things like carbon footprint? Now "Government projects" would mean things like Hospitals, Schools, Roads, Airports e.t.c. But why would government let private investment into it? These are paid by Tax payer money right? And with Government projects, the idea is not profit, it is about providing a service or product to the general public that is required.

Governments seek private investment all the time.  In a UK context, look for "PFI" (private finance initiative)  Lots of hospitals etc were built with PFI money. (It's not free money of course, the private investors want to earn a dividend.  (BTW,  by irony, I think I meant "satire")

All my life I had assumed that government makes all roads, rail, motorway, hospitals, schools, bureaucracy dens e.t.c, using our tax money only and this includes the army and navy and air force. The government might outsource actual work to private contractors e.g Lockhead Martin or Boeing in USA or some other contractor who knows how to actually build a multi-story building (since civil service has no masons) It is for the first time I came to know that this is not always the case. When you say dividend over the investment in government project, where can I learn more about what this means?

Why is this question "closed" when it already has an accepted answer?

Keeping in mind that this whole piece is satirical, the passage reflects an ideal that government always serves the will and best interests of the people.  Thus when government invests in private projects it will conscientiously direct and regulate those projects towards the interests of the public, and when government undertakes public projects those projects are most efficiently completed when outside (private) investment directs the task. Government (in this idealization) is the source of good public will; private industry provides expert management that's the source of proper organization; win/win for everyone.
Of course, this is pollyanna thinking, and in many (if not most) cases the absolute opposite applies. The sardonic humor of the piece comes from the fact that only one of the characters in the dialog seems to understand how vapid the sentiment is — and seems less concerned with the hypocrisy than with how much egg they may all get on their faces — and the other two characters take it as such a bland truism that they have a hard time even remembering that they were going to say it.

It looks like the minister really does not know what is going on since often he is simply not informed or is only told what he needs to know. In this case he was misled and a detailed report was not given to him. So what I understand is that, the statement, though would be true in theory, is practically false as would be expected? I mean after all, the minister was going to take credit based on the assumptions in that statement from Bernard. But the Appleby who is senior of Bernard knows full well that the statement is in practice, false.

@gyuunyuu: Well, I'd interpret it that the minister simply thinks in terms of empty platitudes — good soundbites, in the modern terminology — without wondering or considering whether they have any connection to reality. He's thinking about his speech, and how much public approval he'll get for saying the things he'll say, and can't imagine that it could backfire because of some piffling 'facts'. In other words, he's written as a self-satisfied buffoon. Reminds me of a few someones in modern politics, actually…

From what I have read and heard, the Yes Minister and Yes Prime Minster is quite accurate in its portrayal of government internal working. They try to use lot of fictitous place names and character names from time to time. However, from what I have understood so far is that it is still relevant and is relevant for all governments around the world.

@TedWrigley  "he's written as a self-satisfied buffoon" - no not really. He is written as well-meaning but naive. Ironically, it is his non-elected staff that are the 'real' politicians.

@MikeB Must be a sitcom, someone with so little understanding of politics could never reach the highest office in a real country.

@TedWrigley   No, absolutely not.  The primary theme of the show is that while Hacker is officially in charge, "his staff" have a different agenda.  I have no idea where you get "self satisfied" from.

@MikeB: Sorry, that comment was meant to be directed at Barmar, but I put the wrong tag on it. I'll delete and repost…

@Barmar: I do hope you're being sarcastic…

@TedWrigley Unfortunately, yes.

The show is written with a UK focus from 1980 and forward and this is clearly a reference to the theories around public-private partnership (Search text for United Kingdom).
Spoiler: The implementation did not match the theory.

Ah, for the good old days:  google ngrams for public private partnership and build operate transfer ;-)

It seems to me that the latter half of the quote refers to public-private partnerships, and the former part refers to outsourcing.
